# Custom CSS file styles not being read by ASP.NET Core 5 MVC project

Tags: css, asp.net-core, bootstrap-4, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a custom CSS file `site.css` (which is returning 200 when running the project) I started with a blank ASP.NET Core 5 web application and added MVC functionality in, so I added Bootstrap js/css files and jQuery manually.

When I try to run the project, none of the `site.css` styles show up but there are styles from a file called `scaffolding.less`, which Chrome Dev Tools says is located in `lib/bootstrap/css/less/`. I can't find any `less` file in the `bootstrap/css` folder, so I'm not sure where that is coming from, unless it's added at runtime. I've included the `head` element code of the _Layout.cshtml. Any ideas as to why the `site.css` styles aren't being added?

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro">
    <link href="~/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <link href="~/content/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
```

Here's part of the `site.css` file (bootstrap is making the background white, but it should be the picture from the `url()` repeating (I put the !important in after to try if it would override anything):

```
body {
    padding-top: 70px; /* Required padding for .navbar-fixed-top. Remove if using .navbar-static-top. Change if height of navigation changes. */
    background-image: url('/images/pattern.png') !important;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}
```

Here's a brief view of the `wwwroot` hierarchy:

[image]

Comment: It's Correct it shouldn't have any problems;
use ctrl+F5 to delete cash of site when you run project;
Can you share your css file?

Comment: I added the basic style I want to apply to the body tag. The site.css file is loading successfully and showing up in "Sources" in Chrome Dev Tools.

Comment: its ok; your url is not correct i think; check your url

Comment: Sorry, I added a ".." in the beginning to see if that would do anything, it was originally without the ".." I've tried a "~" as well at the beginning. I'll edit the url to match what I have, I just copied it at the time when I was trying to go up a parent folder.

Comment: @mhhabibi The url seems correct as it's loading when I load the project. I can see the image in Chrome Dev Tools when hovering over the file name.

Comment: Just for testing purposes, try to create a CSS class in the CSS file and try to apply the class to any other element on the web page. See if it works. You could try to test with the background color instead of the background image. It could be possible that your CSS file is loading fine but the CSS code is overridden by other CSS code.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT Yes, I can add a class to site.css with styles and they show up. My guess is the styles are being compiled by Bootstrap to various .LESS files, mainly scaffolding.less, and overriding other styles in the process. I'm just not sure where that's happening as the .LESS file itself doesn't show up in my project. I can alter bootstrap's css, but I'd ideally rather not do that to avoid bad practices.

Comment: You said, you have added BootStrap manually to the project. Could you please inform us, how exactly you have done this? I have added BootStrap to my Asp.Net Core MVC project by right click to project name-> Add-> Client-Side Library-> twitter-bootstrap-> Install. I have placed your code in the `Site.css` file and it works fine.

Comment: That's exactly how I added it, verbatim. It applied body styles from the site.css file and not scaffolding.less?

Comment: For testing purposes, could you try to create a new project and try to perform the same thing to check whether it works. It could help to know whether the issue is related to the specific project.